# Vortex Warp and Spider Climb

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

One of my players is a sorcerer who knows Vortex Warp. Another is a rogue with a pair of Slippers of Spider Climbing.

The sorcerer has posed the question asking whether he could Vortex Warp the rogue onto walls or the ceiling. I *think* the answer is "yes"; walls and ceilings are clearly surfaces, and a creature who can spider climb can be supported by them (presuming the wall/ceiling isn't slippery). However I've been unable to find any people even discussing the combination, much less an answer one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I'd say it should work

The spell requirement is

> The chosen space must be on a surface or in a liquid that can support the target

In this particular case walls and ceilings can support the target, since it wears the Slippers of Spider Climbing, so the spell should work.

As far as I understand, RAI is that you can't use Vortex Warp offensively — drop creatures from cliffs, etc. Teleporting a friendly target to a safe spot is what the spell is designed for.